# Does free version of Cassandra supports In-Memory Caching?

Tags: database, caching, cassandra, in-memory

Does free version of Cassandra supports In-Memory Caching ? OR I need to buy enterprise version for that ?

Comment: As Jeff said, no there is no in memory caching like in DataStax Enterprise. If you need an in-memory-data-grid look at Hazelcast (https://hazelcast.org/) which I like to use a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Cassandra (the free, open source version) has a few different layers of cache. The two most important are:

- A row cache, which caches the head of each CQL partition (if enabled)
- A key cache, which caches the location of data within each file on disk for a given partition key

It DOES NOT have a memory-only storage engine like Datastax Enterprise has. You may be able to tune the row cache to give you a somewhat similar behavior, but it'll always be backed by disk, and it probably won't be quite the same.